# using a spacemouse with autodesk forge

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I just got my hands on  3dconnexion's spacemouse and im trying to set it up to work with the forge viewer, i found some JS samples in the SDK for three.js and it works like a charm.
from my understanding is that both forge and three.js are using webgl if i couldn't help but wonder if it would be possible to convert some of the code in the sample here to directly work with the forge viewer.

link to the complete SDK from 3dconnexion https://3dconnexion.com/my/wp-content/uploads/sites/63/2020/08/3DxWare_SDK_v4-0-2_r17624.zip

link to three.js sample online https://3dconnexion.com/technical_support/web_threejs.html

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, Forge Viewer doesn't support 3dconnexion mouse. You might try to map 3dconnexion's mouse inputs to normal mouse actions and keyboard inputs as a workaround.

Comment: so what you are saying is that the forge api won't allow for such implementation like the one i showed in three.js?

Comment: You can try to implement your [own custom tool](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-tools-forge-viewer) to do so, but there is no official support for this at this moment I'm afraid. Sorry for the bad news,

Comment: how about the JS code that was given in the three.js sample could have be somehow used to control the forge model?

Comment: here https://3dconnexion.com/technical_support/web_threejs.html it works like a charm